# Reloading Express App not working (Angular Frontend)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, express

I'm currently building a Express App with an AngularJS Frontend, and I've come across a rather annoying bug or error in my code, which I can't seem to figure out.

Every Time I try to reload any part of my Page I get the Error (Cannot GET /View1). This is my main Express Route.

```
app.get('/', function(req, res) {
     res.sendfile('./public/index.html');
});
```

**What I tried:**

I've seen other discussions on this topic and they suggest to redirect all routes to Angular, so I tried this:

```
app.get('*', function(req, res) {
 res.sendfile('./public/index.html');
});
```

and setting a base url in my index.html.

**The Problem now:**

This seems to be working but I also built a Express Rest Api and all the sudden I don't get any request parameters in my Api Calls.

```
app.get('/api/location', function(req, res) {
var location = req.query;
Events.getEventsbyLocation(location, function (err, event) {
    if(err){
        throw err;
    }
    res.json(event);
})
});
```

req.query will always be undefined even though it was working perfectly before. I think AngularJs redirects all API calls before request parameters can be submitted.

Anybody else come across this Problem?  Any Help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Can we see your whole express router file? The order you set the rules matters (I think * catches everything, you should put this rule to be use as a fallback), and be aware that for static resources, you shouldn't use `sendFile` I think!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `app.get('/api/location', function(req, res) {...})` in your express server script has to be before the `app.get('*', function(req, res) {...})` route, because express takes the route which matches at first.

Additionally the correct route must be `app.get('/api/:location', function(req, res) {...})`. The `:` indicates a query parameter. Now you can read the location with `var location = req.params.location`.

```
app.get('/api/:location', function(req, res) {
var location = req.params.location;
Events.getEventsbyLocation(location, function (err, event) {
    if(err){
        throw err;
    }
    res.json(event);
})
});

app.get('*', function(req, res) {
 res.sendfile('./public/index.html');
});
```

For parsing `/api/location?lat=42&lng=42` you can use:

```
app.get('/api/location', function(req, res) {
var location = { lat: req.query.lat, lng: req.query.lng };
});
```

`req.query`contains every query parameter. If you request `api/location?lat=42&lng=42&foo=bar` you would get this object:

```
{
  lat: 42,
  lng: 42,
  foo: bar
}
```

Comment: nice! yeah just putting it in the front worked perfectly thanks a lot! The route is correct though and I prefer using req.query over params in this example.

Comment: You're welcome buddy. According to the express API reference `req.query` is for routes like this: `/api?location=foo`. http://expressjs.com/en/api.html#req.query

Comment: yeah I can make a call like /api/location?lat=52&lon=16
and req.query will give me an object {lat: 52, lon: 16} which is pretty neat

Comment: Okay, I thought you you want to parse something like `/api/foo` where "foo" is the location then. I'll update my answer.